# Understanding the bounds of a monotonically increasing sequence $(a_n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> Might it have an upper bound?

Yes. Let $(a_n) = \frac{-1}{n}$. The larger the $n$, the smaller the $k$th term. The sequence tends to $0$ which is the supremum of the given sequence. Since the supremum exists, $(a_n)$ has an upper bound.

> Might it have a lower bound?

Yes. Let $(a_n) = \frac{n}{n + 1}.$ So, our sequence is $\frac12, \frac23, \frac34, \frac45, \frac56 \ldots$ where $\frac12$ is the infimum and thus a lower bound for this sequence exists.

> Must it have an upper bound?

Let $s: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ given by $s(n) = n$ define a sequence. The $k + 1$st term of this sequence is always greater than its $k$th term, so $s$ grows without bound. So, $(a_n)$ doesn't have to have an upper bound.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are correct. You've missed out one combination:

> Must it have a lower bound?

The answer to that question is again "yes": indeed, the first element of the sequence is always a lower bound.